# Doubt concerning Andrews Curve

Tags: gas-laws, phase

> In Andrews Curve of $\ce{CO2}$, what do the horizontal lines signify?

I know that the gas changes to liquid in that region, but since the pressure and temperature is held constant, how does the gas liquefy more and more, even when the pressure and temperature are constant?

Answer (score 1):

Even when pressure and temperature might be constant, the system might be releasing heat energy i.e. the enthalpy is changing. This, precisely, is what is called latent heat.

When CO2 liquifies, the heat from the system is taken away as latent heat, otherwise the enthalpy of condensation would raise the temperature instead of keeping it constant.

Answer (score 0):

If pressure and temperature are held constant, it does not mean the system anthalpy is constant as well.

The heat is taken away to keep temperature constant, otherwise it would heat up due $\ce{CO2}$ enthalpy of condensation.

Similarly, for water boiling, heat is brought in to keep pressure and temperature constant, otherwise it would cool down because of the enthalpy of evaporation.